# Check if there is one "x" for specific rows on multiple Worksheets(Questionnaires)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, automation

I have multiple Worksheets in my Workbook, each of them containing a Questionnaire that looks like this:

[image]

Now I need to check with a Function, if all Questions are properly answered on each Worksheet. There should be one "x" total in columns C-F for each of the Questions. In the screenshot, the function should return false, as there is no "x" for Question 1. I have a lot of these Worksheets, but I could make one function for each as the amount of Questions differ for each Worksheet.

If anyone has any tips/Ideas on how to solve this I would greatly appreciate it.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably start by adding a column to the far right using a =COUNTIFS() expression to count the number of X's in the cols C-F (should be one per row). Use a sum over the column to get the total number of X's on the sheet. This should equal a known value depending on the specific sheet. Create a validation function with Worksheet, expected # of X's, and actual # of X's as arguments. That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer! Seems easy and makes sense